# the right way to notate enharmonic notes

Tags: theory, notation, transcription

Hi I'm in the middle of transcribing Cappella music. The melody is in 'G# minor'. I have in succession  F natural and then up to F#. My question is how should I notate the F natural, do I notate it as F natural or E sharp. The melody is 3/4 The measure before has A natural G# F# |F natural |F#. It's the second to last note where I'm having a query. As I'm. Progressing in the melody, I have the same question do I write C natural or B#? When I have a C natural then a C#

Comment: Be easier to see the part in question.

Comment: I see no reason to write an E sharp instead of F unless there is another F natural soon after the G# making more work for you to go back and forth. Some may disagree though.

Comment: @Tim I'm writing pen to paper so I can't put it up on the forum.

Comment: Without seeing more context, it’s difficult to give a clear answer, but are you sure g# minor is the right choice? That excerpt you posted doesn’t sound much like g# minor at all, which would normally have A# and F double sharp. Of course this could just be a chromatic passage you’re quoting. At any rate, although there are absolutely times that g# minor is appropriate, there’s a possibility that Ab minor would be better since it has less reliance on double accidentals. That being said, if b2 is used often like in the excerpt you quoted, then that wouldn’t help due to the Bbb.

Comment: @ Pat Muchmore it's. G sharp minor, but its a liturgical piece from 1939  he uses alot half steps and melodic and harmonic notes from G sharp minor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We would have to see the score to know for sure.  But it sounds to me that both those enharmonics should be sharps, because they both go up a half step, making them leading tones or scale steps.  Thus, E# rather than F natural, and B# rather than C natural.

Comment: @ Scott Wallace. I wanted to know for sure, for me I also thought that it's should be E# because of the sequence, A natural, G#, F#, now would come E#.